# Typing Text is not visible when EditText is located below SoftKeyboard before the activity resizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

I tried to change `windowSoftInputMode` attribute of activity on Manifests.xml.

I tried with `stateAlwaysHidden`, `stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan`, `stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize`, `adjustPan`, `adjustResize`.

And also, tried with and without `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the layout xml file. And I've done with changing the parent view to ScrollView. But didn't work and now using just RelativeLayout.

But none of them worked. It's the same with default EditText.

Here's the picture of the issue that I am facing.

`ffffff....vddg` this part is at the bottom of the layout when the keyboard is hidden.
And when I press the EditText and Type, it shows black stuff behind other views, at the same time, in the EditText that I type, it shows nothing but looks freezing.

[image]

This issue doesn't happen with Android 7.1 device. But it causes on Android 9.0

Is there any solution?

Comment: Can u share your XML layout file?

Comment: the file is very large. But I get the same issue when you just LinearLayout and many EditText vertically. I think this is the device issue. But I hope there's a way.

Comment: did you try it on any emulator or any other device?

Comment: On Emulator, it works fine. But one device is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of `resizeableActivity` and `android:hardwareAccelerated` in application tag on Manifests.xml

```
    <application
        ...
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:resizeableActivity="true">
```

I think it will resize two times under the hood. So, this kind of weird behaviour happens.